# Access to apache logs from plugin

Tags: plugin-development

how can I access to php logs using plugin ?
I would like in my plugin to show logs, in case there will be some error user can easily check log and send me it.

Comment: so you are talking about PHP error logs not apache access logs?

Comment: @majick yes ;) edited post.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955411/find-out-the-error-logs-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Try and cache block and loggin error manually than you can try this :

```
$mylogfilepath = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'debug.log';
$errormessage = 'SOME ERROR'.PHP_EOL;
error_log($errormessage, 3, $mylogfilepath);
```

Place debug.log file directly inside your plugin. and it will log error to that file. third attribute in error_log set path of file in which log should be recored.